# Always need permission to move, delete, or rename folder or file, Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, permissions, file-management

I restared my computer just now and I'm noticing an issue where Windows File Explorer always asking me for administrator permission to remove, delete, or  rename a file or folder and it's gotten really annoying I want to disable it but I'm not sure how though. Could it be something to do with special permissions? Thanks for help.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which file is it? Or is this on all files? Have you changed permissions of the involved folders?

Comment: Where are the files?  That is a normal messages for files in Program Files (x2), Windows, and someone else's User folder

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others commented, should include some background and what exactly you need, but i'm pretty sure you want to disable UAC, this is the 'service' which asks for permissions when editing / deleting and moving files.

Are you the administrator of the machine, and/or using administrator account, or account with administrator privilages?

https://articulate.com/support/article/how-to-turn-user-account-control-on-or-off-in-windows-10

Comment: Yes, I am one of the admins on the machine. I figured out how to disable to permissions and that seemed to bring the file access denied issue to an end.

Comment: I have this already set to "Never notify", I am the only user - admin on my system but I can't rename or delete text files in C:/ directory created by Windows Installer..

Answer (score 1):

- Type in Windows search bar `Administrative Windows Tools`
- Click to open.
- `Administrative Windows Tools>>>Local Security Policy`
- Local Security Properties window will open
- `Local Polices>>>Security Options`
- Go down to User Account Control: `Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode` (usually 3rd from bottom)
- Click on it and change to Disabled
- Reboot

It is the fastest and only thing that worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me, and additionally there are several more UAC policies necessary to disable for UAC to stop bothering us.